# Using MPI4PY on multiple nodes

Tags: python, mpi, cluster-computing, mpi4py

As the title states I am trying to run a python program on multiple nodes.

I have started by trying to run a hello world script.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
print('hello world from process %d/%d' %(rank,size))
```

I start on a loging node and so to run the task on 1 node I simply request 1 computing node either using swrun -p cpun1 or by using the srun command. They I load mpi and python using module load opence/1.5.1. From there I simply use mpirun python hello_mpi.py.  The program then runs as expected

However, when I request 2 nodes with some n number of tasks

```
srun --partition=cpu --time=4:00:00 --nodes=2 --ntasks-per-node=1 --sockets-per-node=1 --cores-per-socket=1 --threads-per-core=1 --mem-per-cpu=1200 --wait=0 --export=ALL --gres=gpu:v100:0 --pty /bin/bash
```

and then try to run the the hello world program

```
mpirun python hello_mpi.py
```

or

```
mpirun -np 2 python hello_mpi.py
```

it does not print anything and it does not give any errors,  it just keeps on running without doing anything.

I am using mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.1 and python version 3.9.12

Here are some outputs of certain commands to help debug this issue.

```
which python 
/opt/miniconda3/envs/opence-v1.5.1/bin/python
```

```
which mpirun 
/opt/miniconda3/envs/opence-v1.5.1/bin/mpirun.
```

```
which mpi

/usr/bin/which: no mpi in (/opt/miniconda3/envs/opence-v1.5.1/bin:/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin:/opt/openmpi-v4.1.1/bin:/home/jbtrejo2/.local/bin:/home/jbtrejo2/bin:/opt/swsuite/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin).
```

Comment: Could you please detail more the procedure you've followed to run your tasks on 1 node and on 2 nodes ? I'm guessing you're on a cluster and you're asking interactive jobs. What is the node you're when asking for 1 node ? Is it the front node by any chance ? Have you load mpi or python in any way ? Is your cluster running with SLURM ? I guess so since you use `srun` but pls be more specific

Comment: What version of mpi are you then using ? Can you give the return of the command `which mpi` and `which python` ? You might need python3 for this. Also, often implementation of mpi, when not specifying the number of MPI proc to the command mpirun (`mpirun -np 2` for 2 proc), takes the maximum number of MPI proc available and you might not have access to all ressources, so specify this argument can't hurt

Comment: We should not do this in the comment section. Pls edit your post with what you did exactly to make it work with 1 node and not work with 2 nodes, with all the information above : return of which mpirun, which python, mpirun --version, python --version. Also try with argument `mpirun -np 2 python ...` and give the feedback of this